# Laravel 4 - Using Eloquent Models in a custom library class

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I made a library class that I am using for some common functions not provided by Laravel. It's been loaded into /config/app.php under the 'aliases' array, so that shouldn't be the problem.

When I call a method from my class ("InfoParse"), my conroller returns a blank page. I think this has to do with the fact that I'm calling a method from the library which uses Eloquent to interface with the database. I tried adding

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
```

to the top of the file, but that didn't help either.

Is there a specific way I should be setting up my class file so I can use either the DB:: class or Eloquent class?

Below is the function in question:

```
    /**
    * Check to see if this student is already recorded in our student table.
    * If not, add the entry, then return true. 
    * @param int $cwid
    * @return boolean
    */
    public static function checkStudentTableRecords($cwid)
    {
        if(Student::where('cwid', '=', $cwid)->count() != 0)
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
        else 
        {   ##insert the student into our student table
            $studentInfo = self::queryInfoFromCWID($cwid);

            $studentEntry = new Student;
                $studentEntry->cwid = $cwid;
                $studentEntry->fName = $studentInfo['fName'];
                $studentEntry->lName = $studentInfo['lName'];
                $studentEntry->email = $studentInfo['email'];
            $studentEntry->save();

            return TRUE;
        }
    }
```

(note: the self::queryInfoFromCWID() function is calling a function defined earlier in the class)

Answer (score 3):

After some investigation, it turns out I need to format my Eloquent Model calls like this:

```
if(\Student::where('cwid', '=', $cwid)->count() != 0)

...

$studentEntry = new \Student;
```

The backslash is necessary to avoid namespace collision within the Laravel4 application.

Comment: Actually `\\`` at the beginning indicates `global/root` namespace.